# How to make a series of DialogFragments. One closes, another opens automatically?

Tags: android

I have 6 different `DialogFragment` `layouts`. These layouts contains different `Views` and are ment as a guide for the user.

So `DialogFragment` 1 opens, the user confirms (button press) what is written in the `DialogFragment` and then the next one opens etc.

What is the best approach to this?

The different layouts contains Edittex, Buttons, Progressbars, Images, and one of the DialogFragment shall start a `Service` Running in `Background` for Uploading data

I have considered to make them all as a seperate `DialogFragment` and then use the `replace();` method in every `DialogFragment` class like a chain

Comment: create a dialog fragment with view pager...on each page next will move to next tab and on last perform close

Comment: I think your idea is valid.  This is like the idea of a "wizard" that guides the user through the app, right?  I think the fragments would make smooth transitions.

Comment: @daylight Some kind of a wizard. But the layouts include `Lists`, `EditText`, etc. Where the user can interact with these views and one of the `DialogFragment` shall start an `Background Service`for uploading data

Comment: @HRaval Good idea too. I will considere it

Comment: Invoke next dialog inside previous on positive button click listener.

Comment: how about opening the next on when the other dismisses